# Python subprocess.call issue

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, call

When I run the following in Python 3.2.3 in Linux it does nothing...

```
subprocess.call("export TZ=Australia/Adelaide", shell=True)
```

However if I run it in the terminal it works...

```
export TZ=Australia/Adelaide
```

I haven't had an issue with using subprocess.call before. Just seems to be this one. I'm running as a superuser so it's not a sudo thing, and I've also tried putting an r in front of the string to make it a raw string.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to modify environment variables within Python read up on [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ).

Comment: @metatoaster
I've got this but it is still only a local scope within the program. When I exit the program it remains as it was. Is there a way to make the OS update permanently?

    os.environ['TZ'] = 'Australia/Adelaide'
    time.tzset()

Comment: You need to invoke OS/shell specific method of modifying this, such as modifying `.bashrc`, `/etc/environment`, or `/etc/timezone` if your Linux distribution supports that.

Comment: related: [Calling the “source” command from subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7040592/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A subprocess (shell in this case) can't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20524797/4279) ([normally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/211064/4279)) [modify its parent environment.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20524797/4279)

To set the local timezone for the script and its children in Python (on Unix):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone

os.environ['TZ'] = 'Australia/Adelaide'
time.tzset()
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone())
# -> 2015-09-25 05:02:52.784404+09:30
```

If you want to modify the environment for a single command then you could pass `env` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('date', env=dict(os.environ, TZ='Australia/Adelaide'))
# -> Fri Sep 25 05:02:34 ACST 2015
```

Answer (score 3):

Export modifies the environment of the shell.

When you run it through subprocess, a new shell is created, the environment modified and then immediately destroyed.

When you run it in a shell, it modifies the environment of that shell so you can see the effect.